# How to maintain http request Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, http-headers, httprequest

I want to maintain **http** request **Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId**

- When user login to Application i can set **Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId**
- When user logout the **Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId** should not same as user login

Currently i am getting same **Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId** on all pages and i want to generate **Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId** on each login.

I did try on **Global.asax.cs**  but nothing is working.

```
static List<string> sessions = new List<string>();
static object sessionLock = new object();

void Application_SessionStart()
{
    lock (sessionLock) {
        sessions.Add(Session.SessionID);
    }
}

void Application_SessionEnd()
{
    lock (sessionLock) {
        sessions.Remove(Session.SessionID);
    }
}
```

---

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
            {
                if (s == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName || s.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[s].Secure = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;
                }
            }
        }
```

[Please check Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBjMG.png)

Comment: What is your concern, and what are you trying to protect?

Comment: @Win,Actually i am working on application security and i need to set Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId,is it possible ?